# creating a full html file out of webloc in a batch mode

Tags: iphone, macos, bookmarks

I've got over 400 bookmarks saved as .webloc files. I'd like to move them to the iPhone's goodReader app. goodReader cannot open webloc files. It can sork with pdf, html but not webloc.

Do you know of a way or a program that would take a folder as its input, and convert every single .webloc file in it into a PDF version or a html version - so I can grab the converted files and move them onto iPhone.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should be able to convert the files to pdf http://files.macscripter.net/joy/files/webloc2pdf.zip

Comment: It does not work. It only loads one of the weblocs dragged into it in a browser. ( same effect as double clicking on that webloc ).